# How to sum overlapping intervals without including overlap

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

We have collected data in which we measured the length along a measuring tape where particular species overlapped it.  In some cases multiple species may overlap it in the same spot.  I need to figure out how much of the tape was overlapped by plants without counting the same length of tape twice when multiple plants overlap the same spot, and I need to do it grouped by vegetation type (e.g., shrub, tree, etc).  So, I'm answering the question, "how much of the tape is covered by shrubs?" for example.

E.g., imagine the dashed line is the measuring tape, and the asterisks are all different shrubs overlapping the tape.  This is what my data essentially represents right now.  If I counted the length of all the shrubs, I would get a big number, longer than the actual length of the tape...

```
  ***    **    *********
   ****       **     *******
----------------------------
```

...but this is what I need to figure out, the actual length of tape covered by any shrub:

```
  *****  **   **************
----------------------------
```

I hope that makes sense, but here are some examples to explain further if needed:

Example: Imagine I encountered Doug Fir trees that overlapped the measuring tape stretching from the 4' mark to the 10' mark and the 20' mark to the 25' mark.  I also encountered Spruce trees overlapping the tape from the 7' to 14' marks.  I need to know the total length of overlap of tree species (these are both trees), so I will need to sum the lengths of these ranges for both Spruce and Doug Fir.  However, if I just sum all the ranges normally, I will end up counting the 7' to 10' area (sum = 3') twice rather than once, where both Spruce and Doug Firs were covering the tape. So, I will need to subtract 3' from the final value so that this part of the measuring tape is not counted more than once.  So, my ranges are 6', 5', and 7', which totals 18'.  After subtracting the overlapping 3', that gives a total of 15' feet where trees overlap the tape.

Example table below.  I already have the SPECIES, START, END, TYPE, and SUM data.  What I need excel to help me compute are the values shown below the table, which are the sums after accounting for multiple-species overlap. E.g., if Shrub X overlapped from 10' to 20', and shrub Y overlapped from 13' to 25', the total overlap would be from 10' to 25' so fifteen feet of overlap.  Not 22 ft overlap, which is what it would be if you counted each of the ranges separately.)

```
SPECIES START(ft) END(ft) TYPE  SUM (ft)
Dogwood 40.3      40.9    Shrub   0.6
Cedar   52.8      79.5    Tree    26.7
Dogwood 50.2      55.6    Shrub   5.4
Rose    53.8      54.4    Shrub   0.6
Alder   88.2      95.5    Tree    7.3
Clover  75.8      76.2    Forb    0.4
Bunch   82.8      90.3    Grass   7.5
Poa     86.1      95.3    Grass   9.2
Sedge   99.4      100.9   Grass   1.5
Bttrcp  74.5      101.3   Forb    26.8
Elder   105.8     120.3   Shrub   14.5
Bttrcp  110.3     120.2   Forb    9.9
Cedar   90.4      99.9    Tree    9.5



SHRUB SUM   TREE SUM    FORB SUM    GRASS SUM
  20.5       38.4         35.4         14
```

Any guidance in figuring this out would be much appreciated!

Comment: From that table how do you determine the overlap of each plant?

Comment: As is, you have to just look through and figure out where the overlaps are.  For example, looking at it, I can see that the Bunch grass goes from 82.8 to 90.3, while the Poa grass goes from 86.1 to 95.3, so they are overlapping between 86.1 and 90.3.  90.3-86.1 = an overlap of 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that might work. Also, this is only estimated for each TYPE. To get the whole area, repeat for each TYPE:

```
get_max_area(data):
    sort(data, START)
    for i <- 1 to n:
        for j <- i to n:
            if data[j][START] < data[i][START]:         // Two segments overlap
                if data[j][END] < data[i][END]:         // j is fully contained within i
                    ignore(data[j])
                else:                                   // They just overlap
                    merge(data[i], data[i + 1])
                                                        // ELSE: independent segments

    return sum(data[SUM])
```

Ignoring means the segment is not tested anymore. Merging means making segment a(i, j) and b(x, y) a new segment c(i, y). This is just a quick approach, and it takes O(n^2). There must be a better approach.

Comment: Can you help me with how I would integrate this?  A year ago I would have known exactly what to do, but it seems my VBA skills have gone out the window.

Comment: I don't really have that much experience in VBA, I'm sorry.